# cannot sum a column in numpy with nansum

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Ok, here's the preconditions I cannot change:

1. I have a dataframe with a single column
2. it has to be converted and summed in numpy

It looks like that, and it starts from an arbitrary index (I don't think I need to re-index it to save on computational overhead)

```
3    1.32745e+06
4              0
5    6.07657e+08
6            NaN
```

The following does not sum it but returns nan. What am I doing wrong?

```
np_value = np_value.values
print(np.nansum(np_value))
```

Comment: After executing `np_value = np_value.values`,  what is `np_value.dtype`?  It would help if you included a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: How many NaNs does it return? What is its shape and dtype?

Answer (score 1):

Please provide more information on what your np_value is because I believe that is where you are going wrong. I tried this and got the correct answer of 5.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#create numpy array of values
np_values = np.array([1,0,4,np.nan])

#put those values in a dataframe to test
np_values = pd.DataFrame(data=np_values)

#Take just the values of that data
np_value = np_values.values

print(np.nansum(np_value))
```

Answer (score 1):

`np.nansum` can't operate on `object` arrays or string arrays:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.array([1.32745e+06, 0, 6.07657e+08, 'NaN'], dtype=object)
>>> np.nansum(arr)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'

>>> arr = np.array([1.32745e+06, 0, 6.07657e+08, 'NaN'])
>>> np.nansum(arr)
TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type
```

You need to cast it to a numeric type (e.g. `float`) to make it work:

```
>>> np.nansum(arr.astype(float))
608984450.0
```

---

Note: It's pretty obvious in this case that it's an `object` or `string` array because the `0` would display as `0.0` in a float array. Be careful with object arrays, these are slow and often unsupported.